# How to keep changing background color in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, background-color

I want to keep the background changed like a disco screen.
But in this code, the only blue color is shown. What should I fix to change color kept changed?

```
var bgColor = 1
        val bgDrawableIds = intArrayOf(
            R.drawable.purple,
            R.drawable.red,
            R.drawable.blue,
        )
        bgColor++
        disco_display.background = resources.getDrawable(bgDrawableIds[bgColor % bgDrawableIds.size])
```

***xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/disco_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add full code ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a coroutine:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    while (true) {
        disco_display.background = resources.getDrawable(bgDrawableIds[++bgColor % bgDrawableIds.size])
        delay(200L)
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I initialize lifecycleScope?

Comment: You don’t. It‘s a preexisting property of your Activity or Fragment.

Comment: But lifecycleScope is on red color text. And error said Unresolved reference: lifecycleScope

Comment: Have you subclassed AppCompatActivity and are you using the -ktx versions of the Jetpack libraries?